# gRPC server responds with OS Error, grpc_status: 14

Tags: docker, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, grpc-python

Using a basic gRPC client from the Tensorflow Serving examples to get predictions from a model running on docker I get this response:

```
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "OS Error"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1580748231.250387313",
            "description":"Error received from peer",
            "file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc",
            "file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"OS Error","grpc_status":14}"
```

This is what my client currently looks like:

```
import grpc
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2_grpc


def main():
    data = cv2.imread('/home/matt/Downloads/cat.jpg')

    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:8500')
    stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = 'model'
    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'

    request.inputs['image_bytes'].CopyFrom(
        tf.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=[1, data.size]))
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)  # 10 secs timeout
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Can you share the command (and supporting files if applicable) to start the docker container? Did you map the container port `8500` to a port on the host?

Comment: The problem was exactly that! In the docker command I was passing -p 8500:8501 (big facepalm!). With this `OS Error` I was assuming that my client was already connected...
Well spotted. It's alive! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Providing the Solution here even though it is present in Comments Section for the benefit of the community.

The solution is that we need to Invoke the **`Tensorflow Model Server`** by running the Docker Container using the code given below, before executing the Client File:

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" \
    -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two \
    tensorflow/serving &
```

In addition to invoking the Tensorflow Model Server,

1. It will Map the local path of the Model with the path of the Model on the Server and
2. It will map the Ports for communicating with the Tensorflow Model Server. (Port **`8500`** is exposed for **`gRPC`** and Port **`8501`** is exposed for **`REST API`**)

Comment: Hi TF, same problem with ANN Matching Engine on Google Cloud, querying the endpoint. _InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: 
 status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE 
 details = "failed to connect to all addresses" "grpc_status":14}